# How to overload generic function with more specific type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Suppose I have a generic class

```java
public class A<T> {}
```

Then , A is instantiated with B and C, with C extends from another class D :

```java
public class B {}
public class C extends D {}

A<B> b = new A<>();
A<C> c = new A<>();
```

What I'm trying to do is creating a method which accepts `A<T> a` as a parameter. However, I plan to overload the function, so that the instance whose type parameter extends from D can be handled differently.

```java
public class X {
    public static void fun(A<?> a) {}
    public static void fun(A<? extends D> a) {}
}
```

However, the code above cannot be compiled, since it seems that the second `func` also bounds to `Object`. My question would be how to handle such case ? Should I just use `instanceof` , or is there any neater way to accomplish this ?

*Edit : I'm trying to create a function which can handle specific classes with overloading, but there's a catch-all function that will handle other non-specified classes, since I cannot know in advance what classes are going to be used for the type parameter*

Comment: I think it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Will you have more than two functions? Is one supposed to be a catch all? In the last case you might get away with having a switch statement in the catch-all function.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the second `fun` function does not get called?

Comment: Hi @kks21199 , The code cannot be compiled due to same erasure.

Comment: Hi @ManuelRenePaulsToews, thx for the suggestion ! I might need to edit my question to make it clearer. Yes , I'm trying to accomplish both of them : multiple specific methods , and a catch-all method for the unhandled classes. However, I'm still not clear about the switch statement you've suggested. Do you suggest to use switch statements with the classes ? switch with classes doesn't seems to be very clean.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that the second `func` also bounds to `Object`

That is incorrect.

Because of *type erasure*, the generics are removed, so they both become:

```java
public static void fun(A a) {}
public static void fun(A a) {}
```

*Solution:* Don't use overloading, use different method names.